# Calculating time left for a srand code

Tags: php, srand

Currently, I'm generating dynamic code using `srand()` function in PHP:

```
srand(round(time()/30, 0));

$seed = rand(100000, 999999);
```

This would return a 6 digit code, which changes dynamically every 30s, e.g.:

> 295067 (Timestamp: 1459572403)

---

Since the code changes automatically every 30 second, I would like to get the time remaining of the code. Currently, I get it by multiplying the rounded number by 30 and minus it from the current timestamp.

> Example:
>
> Current Timestamp: 1459572403
> Current Timestamp / 30 (rounded to nearest integer): 48652413
> Current Timestamp / 30 (rounded to nearest integer) x 30: 1459572390
> 1459572403 - 1459572390 = **13** (represents **2 seconds** remaining)
>
> Code Generated: **295067**

This method works, however the subtraction statement would return in values of -15 to 14, which in actual fact represents 30s to 0s left.

---

So, is there a better method to get the remaining time left for a generated code, using the stated algorithm?

Comment: I would really appreciate if anyone has a better method, please leave a comment should you require any extra information not stated in the question, thanks!

Comment: You could use `floor()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php instead of `round()`. Than the code changes at 0 and 30 seconds, not on 15 and 45.

Comment: @MarcelPfeiffer Never mind, I thought of a way which is to minus the numbers by 30 then abs it, anyway thanks for the answer!